# Drawing using Canvas in Java FX is very blurry when running on PC

Tags: javafx, canvas, java-8

I used JavaFX for GUI development and Canvas component for drawing. It was very vague when running on PC, but relatively clear on Mac. I want to know the reason

I have tried to use some hd screens to show the Canvas drawing effect,But it's still very vague

```
public class FyEntity {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public FyEntity(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public class FvcVtCurve  extends Canvas {
    public  GraphicsContext gc;
    public  double thisWidth;
    public  double thisHeight;
    public  ArrayList<FyEntity> entityList = new ArrayList<>();

    public FvcVtCurve(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        this.setLayoutX(x);
        this.setLayoutY(y);
        this.setWidth(width);
        this.setHeight(height);
        gc = this.getGraphicsContext2D();
    }
    public void paint() {
        this.drawVtCurve();
    }
    public void drawVtCurve() {
        gc.clearRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
        gc.setLineWidth(1.0);
        gc.setFill(AppUtils.rgb("#000000"));
        gc.setStroke(AppUtils.rgb("#000000"));
        gc.setLineCap(StrokeLineCap.BUTT);
        gc.setLineJoin(StrokeLineJoin.ROUND);
        for (int i = 0;i < entityList.size();i++){
            if (i < entityList.size()-1){
                FyEntity preFyEntity = entityList.get(i);
                FyEntity nextFyEntity = entityList.get(i+1);
                gc.strokeLine(preFyEntity.getX(),preFyEntity.getY(), 
                              nextFyEntity.getX(),nextFyEntity.getY());
                gc.restore();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am wondering whether the gc.restore() inside the drawing loop is at the right place.

Comment: `AppUtils.rgb("#000000")`??? Wouldn't `Color.BLACK` do the trick? Also not sure why the `restore()` call is there. Either it doesn't change a thing or you're putting multiple sets of rendering parameters on the stack without posting any info about this.